LED not turning on on Basys3
I am trying to implement on a Basys3 a MMX ALU. All operations work great, except multiplication. I am using Booth's algorithm and for now I am trying to turn on a LED to let me know when the cycle is done( by that I mean when the result is valid). In the waveform simulation, the signal gets turn on, but on the fpga it does not. Any idea why?
MMX ALU component:
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity MMXAlu is
 Port (
 clk : in std_logic;
 --value1 : out std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
 --value2 : out std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
 --s: out std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
 reset  : in std_logic;
 opcode : in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
 --en : in std_logic;
 --sw : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
 addr1 : in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
 addr2 : in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
--cout : out std_logic;
 --opAdder : out std_logic_vector(18 downto 0);
 --opLogical : out std_logic;
  --opCompare : out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
  --opConv : out std_logic;
  --opShift : out std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
  --opPerformed : out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
s : out std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
cycle_done : out std_logic
  );
end MMXAlu;

architecture Behavioral of MMXAlu is

    signal a : std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
    signal b : std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
    signal operationPerformed : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal selOrAnd : std_logic := '0';
    signal operationsCompare : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal operationsConv : std_logic := '0';
    signal operationsShift : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal operationsAdder : std_logic_vector(18 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal resultLogical : std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
    signal resultConv : std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
    signal resultComp : std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
    signal resultShift : std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
    signal resultAddition : std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
    signal resultMul : std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
    signal couttemp : std_logic;
    signal result : std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
    signal nr_aux : std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
    signal activate_anode : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "0111";
    signal counter : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal lcd_number : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    signal slow_clk : std_logic := '0'; 
    signal clk_div : std_logic_vector(26 downto 0) := (others => '0');

    signal byte : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    signal test,test1 : std_logic;

component rom is
generic(
    address_length : natural := 5;
    data_length : natural := 64
);
Port ( 
    clk : in std_logic;
    en : in std_logic;
    addr1 : in std_logic_vector( (address_length - 1) downto 0);
    addr2 : in std_logic_vector( (address_length - 1) downto 0);
    data_output1: out std_logic_vector( (data_length-1) downto 0);
    data_output2: out std_logic_vector( (data_length-1) downto 0) 
);
end component;

component ControlUnit is
Port(
  opcode : in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
  selOrAnd : out std_logic;
  operationsAdder : out std_logic_vector(18 downto 0);
  operationsCompare : out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
  operationsConv : out std_logic;
  operationsShift : out std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
  operationPerformed : out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0)
  );
end component;


component logicinstrMMX is
Port ( a : in std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
b : in std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
operation : in std_logic;

s : out std_logic_vector(63 downto 0)
);
end component;

component compareinstr is
    Port (
        a : in std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
        b : in std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
        operation : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
        s : out std_logic_vector(63 downto 0)
    );
end component;

component conversioninstr is
    Port (
        a : in std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
        b : in std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
        operation : in std_logic;
        output : out std_logic_vector(63 downto 0)
    );
end component;

component mux5to1_64bit is
    Port (
        data0 : in std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);  -- Data input 0
        data1 : in std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);  -- Data input 1
        data2 : in std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);  -- Data input 2
        data3 : in std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);  -- Data input 3
        data4 : in std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
        data5 : in std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);  -- Data input 4
        sel   : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);   -- Select input (3 bits)
        y     : out std_logic_vector(63 downto 0)  -- Output
    );
end component;

component shifts is
    Port (
        a: in std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);  
        shiftValue : in std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);  
        operation : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0); 
        s: out std_logic_vector(63 downto 0)  
    );
end component;

component adderMMX IS
  PORT (
    a    : in std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
    b    : in std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
    operation : in std_logic_vector(18 downto 0);
    -- Outputs 
    s    : out std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
    --underflow : out std_logic;
    cout : out std_logic
  );
END component;

component multiplicationInstructions is
Port (a: in std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
b : in std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
clk : in std_logic;
reset : in std_logic;
p : out std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);  
cycle_done : out std_logic );
end component;

begin

memory: rom port map(
    clk => clk,
    en => '1',
    addr1 => addr1,
    addr2 => addr2,
    data_output1 => a,
    data_output2 =>b
);

co : ControlUnit port map(
    opcode => opcode,
    selOrAnd => selOrAnd,
    operationsCompare => operationsCompare,
    operationsConv => operationsConv,
    operationsShift => operationsShift,
    operationsAdder => operationsAdder,
    operationPerformed => operationPerformed
);

logicinstructions : logicinstrMMX port map(
    a => a,
    b => b,
    operation => selOrAnd,
    s => resultLogical
);

compareinstructions : compareinstr port map(
    a => a,
    b => b,
    operation => operationsCompare,
    s => resultComp
);

conversioninstructions : conversioninstr port map(
    a => a,
    b => b,
    operation => operationsConv,
    output => resultConv
);

shiftinstructions : shifts port map(
    a => a,
    shiftValue => b,
    operation => operationsShift,
    s => resultShift
);

adders : adderMMX port map(
    a => a,
    b => b,
    operation => operationsAdder,
    s => resultAddition,
    cout => test
);

multiplication: multiplicationInstructions port map(
    a => a,
    b => b,
    clk => clk,
    reset => reset,
    p => resultMul,
    cycle_done => cycle_done
    );
    
mux5to1 : mux5to1_64bit port map(
    data0 => resultAddition,
    data1 => resultComp,
    data2 => resultConv,
    data3 => resultLogical,
    data4 => resultShift,
    data5 => resultMul,
    sel => operationPerformed,
    y => result
    );
    

--opAdder <= operationsAdder;
--opCompare <= operationsCompare;
--opConv <= operationsConv;
--opShift <= operationsShift;
--opLogical <= selOrAnd;
--opPerformed <= operationPerformed;
--value1 <= a;
--value2 <= b;
s <= result;

end Behavioral;


SSD component:
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity SSD is
    Port ( 
        nr_aux : in std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
        clk : in std_logic;
        btn : in std_logic;
        seg : out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
        an : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
    );
end SSD;

architecture Behavioral of SSD is


signal activate_anode : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "0111";
signal counter : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal lcd_number : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
signal slow_clk : std_logic := '0';
signal clk_div : std_logic_vector(16 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal byte : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal counter2 : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal btn_reg : std_logic := '0'; -- Register for btn signal
signal btn_rising_edge : std_logic := '0'; -- Edge detection signal

begin
-- Clock divider to create slow clock
process(clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        clk_div <= clk_div + 1;
        if clk_div = "11000011010100000" then -- Divide 100 MHz to ~1 kHz
            slow_clk <= not slow_clk;
            clk_div <= (others => '0');
        end if;
    end if;
end process;


--counter for displaying every 4 bytes
-- Detect rising edge of btn
process(clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        btn_rising_edge <= not btn_reg and btn; -- Detect rising edge
        btn_reg <= btn; -- Update btn register
    end if;
end process;

-- Update counter2 on btn rising edge
process(clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        if btn_rising_edge = '1' then
            counter2 <= counter2 + 1;
            if (counter2 = "11") then
                counter2 <= "00";
            end if;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;


-- Counter for multiplexing
process(slow_clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(slow_clk) then
        counter <= counter + 1;
    end if;
end process;

-- Activate anode based on counter
process(counter)
begin

    case counter is
        when "00" => 
            activate_anode <= "0111"; 
           lcd_number <= byte(15 downto 12);
        when "01" => 
            activate_anode <= "1011"; 
           lcd_number <= byte(11 downto 8);
        when "10" => 
            activate_anode <= "1101"; 
           lcd_number <= byte(7 downto 4);
        when "11" => 
            activate_anode <= "1110"; 
            lcd_number <= byte(3 downto 0);  
        when others => 
            activate_anode <= "1111"; -- All OFF (should not happen)
    end case;

end process;

process(counter2)
begin

case counter2 is
    when "00" => byte <= nr_aux(15 downto 0);
    when "01" => byte <= nr_aux(31 downto 16);
    when "10" => byte <= nr_aux(47 downto 32);
    when "11" => byte <= nr_aux(63 downto 48);
    when others => byte <= (others => '0');
end case;

end process;

-- Assign `an` to activate anodes
an <= activate_anode;

-- Assign segment values based on lcd_number
process(lcd_number)
begin
    case lcd_number is
        when "0000" => seg <= "1000000";  -- "0"
        when "0001" => seg  <= "1111001";  -- "1"
        when "0010" => seg  <= "0100100";  -- "2"
        when "0011" => seg  <= "0110000";  -- "3"
        when "0100" => seg  <= "0011001";  -- "4"
        when "0101" =>seg  <= "0010010";  -- "5"
        when "0110" => seg  <= "0000010";  -- "6"
        when "0111" => seg  <= "1111000";  -- "7"
        when "1000" => seg  <= "0000000";  -- "8"
        when "1001" => seg  <= "0010000";  -- "9"
        when "1010" => seg  <= "0001000";  -- "A"
        when "1011" => seg  <= "0000011";  -- "b"
        when "1100" => seg  <= "1000110";  -- "C"
        when "1101" => seg  <= "0100001";  -- "d"
        when "1110" => seg  <= "0000110";  -- "E"
        when "1111" => seg  <= "0001110";  -- "F"
        when others => seg  <= "1111111"; -- Blank display
    end case;
end process;

end Behavioral;


Top level component:

library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity toplevel is
Port (
sw : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
btnU : in std_logic;
clk : in std_logic;
seg : out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
LED : out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
an : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)

 );
end toplevel;

architecture Behavioral of toplevel is

signal result : std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
signal temp : std_logic;
signal slow_clk : std_logic := '0';
signal clk_div : std_logic_vector(26 downto 0) := (others => '0');

component SSD is
   Port ( 
        nr_aux : in std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
        clk : in std_logic;
        btn : in std_logic;
        seg : out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
        an : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
    );
end component;

component MMXAlu is
 Port (
 clk : in std_logic;
 reset  : in std_logic;
 opcode : in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
 addr1 : in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
 addr2 : in std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
s : out std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
cycle_done : out std_logic
  );
end component;

begin

alu: MMXAlu port map(
    clk => clk,
    reset => sw(15),
    opcode => sw(14 downto 10),
    addr1 => sw(4 downto 0),
    addr2 => sw(9 downto 5),
    cycle_done => led(0),
    s => result);
   
   
 display: SSD port map(
    clk => clk,
    nr_aux => result,
    btn => btnU,
    an => an,
    seg => seg);


LED(1) <= '1';
--LED <= temp;

end Behavioral;


If nothing seems wrong here, I can also post my Booth's implementation, but as I said, on the simulation it works fine and my goal so far is to get that led turned on.
